# Order of disposal for base classes

Tags: c#, .net, dispose

When a derived class overrides Dispose should the base class Dipose be called first before the derived class disposes of any local resources?

The reason I ask is because someone on our team is saying yes for every scenario, I'm trying to work out if this is good idea or just 'cargo cult' programming, I don't have a strong view either way.

Before:

```
 public override void Dispose()
 {
     base.Dispose();

     if (!_isDisposed)
     {
         _isDisposed = true;

         if (_foo != null)
         {
             _foo.Dispose();
         }
     }
 }
```

After:

```
 public override void Dispose()
 {
     if (!_isDisposed)
     {
         _isDisposed = true;

         if (_foo != null)
         {
             _foo.Dispose();
         }
     }

     base.Dispose();
 }
```

Note: I'm not looking for how to implement the basic dispose pattern but more clarification from peoples experiences.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**"It depends"**

You can't have a hard-and-fast rule for this, because the order you need to call dispose will depend on the implementation of the classes.

Sometimes you might want it at the start, sometimes at the end, and sometimes in the middle. Most of the time, it probably won't matter.

Generally speaking, people seem to call it first (in the absence of any other reason to call it at a different time).

One reason to lean towards calling it first is that then the derived class has a chance to do special stuff afterwards if it needs to.

Comment: "One reason to lean towards calling it first is that then the derived class has a chance to do special stuff afterwards if it needs to" - true, but by the same token, one reason to call it last is that then the derived class has a chance to do special stuff beforehand :)

Comment: @Matthew Watson: I do agree with your assumption, but what if we consider, the drived class might be dependent on a resource which has been allocated in the base, then for any reason if base tries to dispose it first, then drived class has no chance to make it right. can we consider it this way?

Comment: @MortezaAzizi Well the disposal order is controlled by the derived class, so it can make sure that the base is disposed after the derived if needed.

Answer (score 1):

You should think about the consequences of the different approaches.  In most cases, the `IDisposable` objects owned by the base class will be independent of those owned by the derived class, and the order of disposal won't matter, provided none of the `Dispose` methods throws an Exception (*).

If it's critical to release an `IDisposable` resource, you could consider using try/finally to ensure all `Dispose` methods are called - but this isn't universally done.  For example, the [System.Component.Container](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.container.aspx) class manages and disposes multiple `IDisposable` objects, but makes no attempt to ensure they are all disposed if an exception is thrown.

(*) It's perfectly legitimate for `Dispose` to throw: for example a `FileStream` might attempt to flush data to a network resource that's no longer available during `Dispose`.

Answer (score 0):

Dispose object in the reverse order to create. So firstly is created base class, so it should be dispose in the end, and so on...